# Saving docx as a filtered HTML flattens some images to a height of 1

Tags: html, ms-word, chm

I've inherited a build system that uses chmProcessor to convert a docx file to a chm file.  Not ideal obviously, and I plan to replace it in the future, but for the immediate future I'm stuck with it.

chmProcessor starts by using Word to resave the docx as a filtered html file.  In the file there's a warning icon that's used extensively.  For some reason when converting the file to html this icon is changed to have a height of 1 about halfway through.  In the html it's explicitly given a height of 1 pixel, and it's also saving a second copy of the image that is only 1 pixel high.

I've tried replacing it at that point with a different identical image and a completely different image to no effect.  I've even converted it into html, updated the html to use the correct image with the correct height and converted it back into a docx.  When I convert it into html again the image is flattened again.

Deleting different sections of the document only moves the problem later in the file, and it doesn't seem to matter which bits I delete.

There's obviously some subtlety in the docx that is causing this but I honestly have no idea what.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I didn't understand what workflow you are using and have never seen this kind of behavior before.

I take a well structured ***Word.docx*** file, add it as a source file in CHMProcessor and convert directly to a ***CHM help file***. Therefore, I don't need any filtered HTML files. Is this meant as an intermediate step in WORD in your case? Please [edit] your question, add more details about your process and the used program versions and a download possibility with a reduced Word file to be able to understand the error at all.

Comment: This is not apparently a programming question. Questions on general usage of Word are off-topic for Stack Overflow; they should be asked on and appropriate end-user forum (e.g., MS Answers).